# Fileupload not working within FormView inside update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

i have file upload control in FormView and that FormView is inside update panel when i try to update FormView everything works but image path from fileupload don't save after GridView1 rowcommand please help me...

page.aspx

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnl1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" Width="20px">
                     <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <table>
         <tr>
                                <td style="border-style: dashed dashed dashed none; dashedborder-style: none dashed none dashed;
                                    border-width: thin; border-color: #000000;">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text="user" BorderStyle="None"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td style="border-style: dashed none dashed none; border-width: thin; border-color: #000000;">
                                    <uc1:Employee ID="UCEmployee" runat="server" />
                                </td>
                                <td style="border-style: dashed none dashed none; border-width: thin; border-color: #000000;">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label15" runat="server" Text="percent"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td style="border-style: dashed none dashed dashed; border-width: thin; border-color: #000000;">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPartnership" runat="server" Width="60px"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgAddPersonel" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/images/icons/add.gif"
                                        OnClick="imgAddPersonel_Click" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="border-style: none dashed dashed dashed; border-width: thin; border-color: #000000;"
                                    colspan="4">
                                    &nbsp;
                                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
                                    </asp:GridView>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
    <tr>
                                  <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label20" runat="server" Text="attachment" ></asp:Label>                        
                            </td>
                                  <td colspan="3">
                                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server"/>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
      </table>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:FormView>
```

.cs file

```
protected void imgAddPersonel_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
           entity.EmployeeId = lovid;
            entity.Partnership = Partnership;
            entity.EmployeeFullName = USEmployee.Des;
            Listentity.Add(entity);
            HttpContext.Current.Session["Listentity"] = Listentity;
            datagridbind(ref gd);
            USEmployee.LOVId = null;
            USEmployee.Des = "";
            txtPartnership.Text = "";
            USEmployee.Focus();
        }
    }
    protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Delete1")
        {
            GridView gd = ((GridView)FormView1.FindControl("GridView1"));
            int rowindex = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
            int employeeid = (int)gd.DataKeys[rowindex]["EmployeeId"];
            Listentity = (List<SuggestionEmployee>)Session["Listentity"];
            Listentity.RemoveAt(rowindex);
            Session["Listentity"] = Listentity;
            datagridbind(ref gd);      
        }
    }

protected void FormView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FormView1.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Insert)
        {
            ImageButton lb = (ImageButton)FormView1.FindControl("imgAddPersonel");
            ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterPostBackControl(lb);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**EXPLANATION**

This is the issue which normally occurs with `Fileupload` control.  Your `FileUpload` control will not have the image path because your file upload control is in the `UpdatePanel`.
When you run the program your `UpdatePanel` will send request to the server and that request will be send to the `ajax` therefor file upload control will not triggered and not work as expected.

**ANSWER**

You need to remove your `FileUpload` control and place it out side the `UpdatePanel`.
Then it will work as expected. I hope this information will be useful to you.

Have a great day.!

Comment: thanks. but i know that,because my solution it must in updatepanel

Comment: Okay frnd then you need to use the ajax file upload control that will definitely solve your problem

Comment: Because I faced so much of problem with the file upload control. If you want I can help you with the code

Comment: can i use   ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterPostBackControl(control); for row command?

Comment: I have gridview tHat add personnel "GridView1", when i delete any row FileUpload1 not work. I think if i register LinkButton maybe resolve my problem